Movie about a girl luring and locking a man into a white room with only a computer
I don't recall much other than a woman chatting to a man via internet chat room and eventually lures him in to meet her. He goes to a train station, opens a door to a white room where she is sitting, he goes to talk to her however she leaves and he then becomes stuck in that room.
I believe the only way for him to escape is to do the same, by luring someone else in.
I think it may have only been a short and not a full length

I've seen this film can't remember the name but I'm sure the guy in it was Samuel Johnson. Australian actor from a show called SECRET LIFE OF US

I've seen this short film; I'm sure the guy in it was Australian actor Samuel Johnson from a show called The Secret Life of Us. The short is called ICQ (2001). From a synopsis:

After an eerie premonition a young man finds himself searching the internet for clues - which lead him to a strange website and a mysterious girl who seems trapped [in a white room].


You should be able to edit your original answer instead of posting another one. Also, flesh out your answer- put in a short plot summary, a link to the IMDb or wiki page, why it's the right answer.
